# importing xlwings module into python 3.4

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to use the new excel integration module xlwings 
It works like a charm under Anaconda 2.0 for python 2.7
but I'm getting this error under Anaconda 2.0 for python 3.4
the xlwings file does contain class Workbook so I don't understand why it can't import it
when I simply use the xlwings file in my project for 3.4 it works just fine

File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from xlwings import Workbook, Range, Chart, **version**

ImportError: cannot import name 'Workbook'

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I will look into it asap. In the meantime, I have logged an issue https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/26

Comment: This has now been fixed in v0.1.1, see Release Notes here: http://docs.xlwings.org/whatsnew.html#v0-1-1-june-27-2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `"C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings__init__.py"`

Try  changing  `from xlwings import Workbook, Range, Chart, __version__`

to `from xlwings.xlwings import Workbook, Range, Chart, __version__`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham do you have a hint of what's the change between Python 3.3 and 3.4 that causes the error?

Comment: @FelixZumstein, was it working on python 3.3 as is? It seems to be giving the same error using pyenv on python 3.3.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah I figured it seems more a 3 vs 2 issue with regards to absolute imports than 3.4 vs 3.3. Only ran it on WinPython 3.3 where it runs fine. I opted now for `from __future__ import absolute_import` `from .xlwings import Workbook, Range, Chart, __version__` which seems to work fine for 2 and 3

Comment: @FelixZumstein, that works fine on ubuntu also, using 3.3 and 3.4.