# trouble importing xlwings module into python 2.7 on Mac

Tags: python-2.7

I am attempting to use xlwings with Python 2.7.8 on Mac, but when I enter this code:

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range, Chart
```

I receive this error message:

```
cannot import name Workbook
```

This appears to be the the same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121692/importing-xlwings-module-into-python-3-4) with Python 3, but I am experiencing the same issue now with Python 2.7.8. I had no trouble importing mysql.connector so I don't think this is an issue with the Path variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ash

Comment: What version of xlwings and numpy are you using? and are you using the system installation of Python on Mac?